# Partitioning HDD on Windows 64 bit

Tags: windows, partitioning, ntfs

I got here Dell laptop running Windows 7 professional 64 bit. I just installed it. I am using Windows's Disk Management tool to partition the disk. There is C partition, then System Reserved partition (100  MB created by the OS), and the third one I am trying to create. I format it. Once it is done it is written that's NTFS Healthy  Simple Dynamic Volume. The partition I am trying to create consists of two pieces joined together ( at least on that tool it is depicted in that way). But it does not appear on My Computer Window; I can't access it. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is done. I only needed to assign the partition letter explicitly.